# [CTS]android.net.cts.DnsTest#testDnsWorks- Fails

Tags: android, cts

Preconditions:
1. Set up CTS environment on nexus5.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Connect device to ubuntu PC
2. Run android-cts/tools/.cts-tradefed
3. Run command: run cts --class android.net.cts.DnsTest --method testDnsWorks

Expected result:
Pass

Actual result:
Failed

Can anybody tell why its failing?? is ita set up issue ?

Comment: run cts --class android.net.cts.DnsTest --method testDnsWorks.
This case totally depends on Wifi Access point.
re-execute the TC after checking that the AP is connected to IPV6 network.

Answer (score 0):

It's should be an environment issue,

this test needs to be executed on a Wifi AP that supports IPv6.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63499

Answer (score 0):

Check in CTS code, it's trying to reach both IPv4 and IPv6.
If your network doesn't support IPv6 but IPv4 this test won't pass.

check if your network supports IPv6 or not, at http://test-ipv6.com/